# How to get maximum or minimum from multiple sets of calculated values with xpath

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I need the maximum of three three kinds of values.
I've got a structure similar to this.

note:the first two answers are based on a previous example xml (in set 2 of night the max-above-average was 8). This was confusing, so I changed it to 7.

```
<data>
    <record>
        <max>60</max>
    </record>
    <day>
        <set>
            <average>49</average>
            <max-above-average>3</max-above-average>
        </set>
        <set>
            <average>45</average>
            <max-above-average>9</max-above-average>
        </set>
    </day>
    <night>
        <set>
            <average>50</average>
            <max-above-average>5</max-above-average>
        </set>
        <set>
            <average>52</average>
            <max-above-average>7</max-above-average>
        </set>
    </night>
</data>
```

Now I need the maximum of the record, day and night. This would be maximum: 60, the value of the record in this example: 60 = 60, > 49 + 3, 45 +9, 50 + 5, 52+7. Day and night maximums need to be calculated. Because of this

> max(//record/max | //day/set/(average + max-above-average)) | //night/set/(average +max-above-average))

does not work. The |-sign only  works for nodes.
It gives following error:

> Required item type of second operand of '|' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:double

I'm using xpath 2.0 and xslt 2.0.

Comment: What implementation are you using, which XPath version do they offer? What's the expected output? What's wrong with the code you have (error message, wrong output)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here are the wanted two XPath 2.0 expressions** (for producing the "max" and the "min" value, respectively):

```
max(/*/(day|night)/*/(average+max-above-average))
```

**and**

```
min(/*/(day|night)/*/(average -min-above-average))
```

**XSLT 2.0 - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
 max: <xsl:text/>
  <xsl:sequence select=
    "max(/*/(day|night)/*/(average+max-above-average))"/>
 min: <xsl:text/>
  <xsl:sequence select=
    "min(/*/(day|night)/*/(average -min-above-average))"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<data>
    <record>
        <min>40</min>
        <max>60</max>
    </record>
    <day>
        <set>
            <average>49</average>
            <max-above-average>3</max-above-average>
            <min-above-average>15</min-above-average>
        </set>
        <set>
            <average>45</average>
            <max-above-average>9</max-above-average>
            <min-above-average>2</min-above-average>
        </set>
    </day>
    <night>
        <set>
            <average>50</average>
            <max-above-average>5</max-above-average>
            <min-above-average>6</min-above-average>
        </set>
        <set>
            <average>52</average>
            <max-above-average>8</max-above-average>
            <min-above-average>11</min-above-average>
        </set>
    </night>
</data>
```

**the two XPath expressions are evaluated and the results of these evaluations are copied to the output**:

```
 max: 60
 min: 34
```

**Update**:

The OP says in a comment that he wants "maximum of day and night ànd record" -- I really don't understand what he means by that.

**Here is my attempt at *guessing*:**

```
max(
      (/*/record/max, 
       /*/(day|night)/*/(average+max-above-average, average+min-above-average)
       )
    )
```

**When implanted in the XSLT transformation (above), this produces:**

```
 max: 64
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But - I've made my question a bit clearer - the exact problem was that I need the maximum of day and night ànd record. The XPath I gave as an example doesn't work because the |-sign only works for nodes.

Comment: @Pikachu, I definitely don't understand what you are saying -- please explain and provide the exact wanted results -- it wouldn't be difficult to give you the wanted expressions, once I understand what you really want.

Comment: @Pikachu, Please, see my update -- it reflects what I currently make out from your comment.

Comment: Thank you very much. You almost gave me what I was looking for: max(
      (/*/record/max, 
       //(day|night)/*/(average + max-above-average)
       )
    ) Much simpler than the other answer ;)

Comment: @Pikachu, You are welcome. And yes, XPath 2.0 and next is a great language.

Answer (score 1):

An XSLT 1.0 approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:variable name="recordMax" select="record/max" />
    <xsl:variable name="dayMax">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="day" mode="max" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="nightMax">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="night" mode="max" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:call-template name="Max">
      <xsl:with-param name="v1" select="$recordMax" />
      <xsl:with-param name="v2">
        <xsl:call-template name="Max">
          <xsl:with-param name="v1" select="$dayMax"  />
          <xsl:with-param name="v2" select="$nightMax" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[set]" mode="max">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="set" mode="max">
      <xsl:sort select="average + max-above-average"
                data-type="number"
                order="descending" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="set" mode="max">
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
      <xsl:value-of select="average + max-above-average" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="Max">
    <xsl:param name="v1" />
    <xsl:param name="v2" />

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($v2 > $v1)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$v1" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$v2" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
60
```

Comment: OK, thanks, still a lot longer than I had thought. I'll try this, but still hope someone has a simpler solution.